# Chef resource, script inside "not_if" is not working

Tags: bash, chef-infra

I have a chef_resource that looks like this

```
bash 'regenerate-master-list' do
  code <<-EOH
  rm -f /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/conf.yaml
  EOH
  action :run
  notifies :create, 'cookbook_file[/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/conf.yaml]', :immediately
  not_if "diff <(cat /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/master_list) <(redis-cli -p 26379 info sentinel | grep name | sed 's/,.*//' | cut -d '=' -f 2-)"
end
```

this block always executes because the `not_if` is falsey, when I try to run it manually I see the expected results which is no diff. Is there anything I should add to the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create an `execute` resource with command equal to your `bash not_if` guard.

```
execute "diff <(cat /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/master_list) <(redis-cli -p 26379 info sentinel | grep name | sed 's/,.*//' | cut -d '=' -f 2-)"
```

You can do it right on the target machine in cookbook cache folder, and then run chef client with `chef-client --skip-cookbook-sync`, which does not update local cookbook cache. Chef will fail with the run and you will see the output.

My guess is, chef cannot run redis-cli, because it is not in PATH for chef.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hacky but I just added a new bash resource

```
# diff check_sum of current list vs. existing, drop a file for next resource to pickup
bash 'master-list-checksum' do
  code <<-EOH
  diff <(cat /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/master_list) <(redis-cli -p 26379 info sentinel | grep name | sed 's/,.*//' | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
  test $? -eq 0 || touch /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/update_list
  EOH
  action :run
end

# remove config to be replaced with new one
bash 'regenerate-master-list' do
  code <<-EOH
  rm -f /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/conf.yaml
  rm -f /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/update_list
  EOH
  action :run
  notifies :create, 'cookbook_file[/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/conf.yaml]', :immediately
  only_if { File.exists?("/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/redis_sentinel.d/update_list") }
end
```